# Port Xamarin.Forms project to Blazor Web Assembly

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have quite an extensive forms project with target platforms in all UWP, iOS, Android. Dependency Services, Custom Renderers for all platforms, etc.

I have been asked to port this entirely or as much as possible C# code to Blazor Web Assembly. I would like to if it's possible and if so how?

Comment: If delivery of this can be delayed until .Net Maui releases, this might be a much easier task then. Read up on .Net 6 and Maui.

Comment: But still how will the porting be done. Is there some article or process that you can guide me towards @ToolmakerSteve

Comment: @ShubhamTyagi have a look at some videos related to maui and blazor. that will help you understand.